# Is it possible to add data to option using shorthand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-select

I'm trying to add dynamic information to an option in a select element.  I want to use data because it is compliant with all browsers.  I tried using alt and it does show up in chrome, but I'm not sure if it is proper to have an alt tag on an option element.

```
jQuery(el).append($('<option>', {
    value: index,
    text: column_persistence[index],
    alt: check_box_id
}));
```

How do I add a data-attribute dynamically using the append jQuery method?

Comment: Yes, don't use `alt`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to do this:

```
$(el).append($('<option>', {
    value: index,
    text: column_persistence[index],
    "data-alt": check_box_id
}));
```

Or:

```
$(el).append($('<option>', {
    value: index,
    text: column_persistence[index]
}).data("alt", check_box_id));
```

Or:

```
$(el).append($('<option>', {
    value: index,
    text: column_persistence[index]
}).attr("data-alt", check_box_id));
```

These should result in the HTML Element:

```
<option value="1" data-alt="chbk-1">Column Name</option>
```

Comment: The second method is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`alt` (short for "alternate text") is only appropriate and valid on `<img>` elements and is used for accessibility reasons. It what screen readers will read aloud to visually impaired users and it is what will be displayed in lieu of the image when the image can't be displayed.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)**:

> **alt**
>
> This attribute defines the alternative text describing the image. Users will see this text displayed if the image URL is wrong,
>   the image is not in one of the supported formats, or if the image is
>   not yet downloaded.
>
> Browsers do not always display the image referenced by the element.
>   This is the case for non-graphical browsers (including those used by
>   people with vision impairments), if the user chooses not to display
>   images, or if the browser cannot display the image because it is
>   invalid or an unsupported type. In these cases, the browser may
>   replace the image with the text defined in this element's alt
>   attribute. You should, for these reasons and others, provide a useful
>   value for alt whenever possible.
>
> Omitting this attribute altogether indicates that the image is a key
>   part of the content, and no textual equivalent is available. Setting
>   this attribute to an empty string (alt="") indicates that this image
>   is not a key part of the content, and that non-visual browsers may
>   omit it from rendering.

To add the `data` attribute and data for it simply access the `.data()` method and pass the `-name` and value for the attribute:

```
$( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );
```

With the `.append()` method, you would set the attribute almost as you would any other, but be sure to enclose the entire attribute in quotes. It would look like this:

```
jQuery(el).append($('<option>', {
    value: index,
    text: column_persistence[index],
    "data-Name": theValue
});
```

See [this](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for documentation.